# How to have a navigation full ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, navigation

I have a question.

I visited a site : http://currenthiphop.com/. And when I clicked on a link, the link on adress bar change to `http://currenthiphop.com/#!/` + link. (like Twitter, Faceboook...)

However, in the attribut `href`, there is no `#!`. Why ?

Is is a ajax navigation isn't ? 
How can I do something like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This oughta get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/f6dBV/

**EDIT** - jsFiddle is actually not showing the location.hash bit. Here it is on my website: http://jfcoder.com/test/hash.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.content {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').each(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('href');
        id = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('/'));
        id = id.substring(0,id.indexOf('.'));
        $(this).attr('rel',id);
    });
    $('#home').show();
    $('#menu a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
        location.hash = '#!/'+$(this).attr('rel');
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a> -
    <a href="one.html">One</a> -
    <a href="two.html">Two</a> -
    <a href="three.html">Three</a>
</div>
<div id="home" class="content">
    Home content.
</div>
<div id="one" class="content">
    One content.
</div>
<div id="two" class="content">
    Two content.
</div>
<div id="three" class="content">
    Three content.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Steffi - I think your question is different than this one, so you might consider opening a new question and asking if this type of url modification affects SEO. Your in-page links are still intact, so I would imagine SEO would be improved. However, I'm not an SEO expert. Additionally, this is just a starting-off point; there are a number of ways this could go (getting content through $.get() for instance), plus some other ways it could be optimized depending on requirements and other considerations.

Answer (score 2):

It is [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location). Like in Facebook it is made with javascript. It is used to avoid use of **GET** and reload the page.

[basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/qDjYx/) - in the folder where are the php page and JavaScript you have some images (1.png, 2.png ... etc). Like Facebook (some time ago) if you copy the link and paste it, js checks if there is any hash and redirects you to the wanted image. The code is old, and it is not the best.

Comment: So, it's used to avoid reload the page. Great ! How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jared Farrish.

I have one little extra addition that will allow you to get the active content after you refresh the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').each(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('href');
        id = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('/'));
        id = id.substring(0,id.indexOf('.'));
        $(this).attr('rel',id);
    });
    active_page = location.hash.substring(location.hash.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
    if (active_page=='')
    {
        active_page='home'
    }
    $('#'+active_page).show();
    $('#menu a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
        location.hash = '#!/'+$(this).attr('rel');
        return false;
```